# Spectral measure of 1-dimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, spectral-theory, fourier-transform

I want to compute the spectral measure of the 1-dimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process with covariance function 
\begin{align}
\rho(t) = e^{-|\beta|t}, \qquad t \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{align}
Since $\rho$ is a proper covariance function, Bochner's theorem says that $\rho$ is the covariance function of some stationary Gaussian random field if and only if
\begin{align}
\rho(t) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{i\omega t}\ d\mu(\omega),
\end{align}
for some finite non-negative symmetric Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Now, I know as well that if $\mu \ll \lambda$, when $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue-measure, $\rho$ could be written as
\begin{align}
\rho(t) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{i\omega t}f(\omega)\ d \omega,
\end{align}
where $f$ is the spectral density, i.e. the Fourier transform of the covariance function $\rho$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
f(\omega)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-i\omega t} \rho(t)\ dt.
\end{align}
However, I do not know see how to compute the spectral measure explicitly. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

At first, the covariance function of OU process should be $\rho(t)=e^{-\beta|t|}$, $\beta>0$. If this is true, then the spectral density is the following:
\begin{align}
f(\omega)&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i\omega t}\rho(t)\,dt
=\frac1{2\pi}\biggl[\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-i\omega t}e^{-\beta|t|}\,dt+
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-i\omega t}e^{-\beta|t|}\,dt\biggr]\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\Bigl[\frac{1}{\beta-i\omega}+\frac{1}{\beta+i\omega}\Bigr]
=\frac{\beta}{\pi(\beta^2+\omega^2)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Okido, thanks for your reaction. How to find the spectral measure from the spectral density?